# Applying class in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, classname, class-names

Newbie here. I'm trying to convert this class
`` <div className={`banner-row marquee  ${playMarquee && "animate"}`}> ``  for next.js.
I can't figure out the best way to do it. Anyone can help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to convert the class for use in a Next.js project would be to use a ternary operator to conditionally assign the "animate" class based on the value of playMarquee.

```
<div className={`banner-row marquee ${playMarquee ? "animate" : ""}`}>
```

You can also use classnames npm package, it's a small JavaScript utility for conditionally joining classNames together.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
<div className={classNames('banner-row', 'marquee', { animate: playMarquee })}>
```

You can use whichever approach you find most readable and maintainable for your project.